# WordPress - Use user meta in 'user_register' after new registration

Tags: user-registration, wp-register-script

I am trying to access user meta by $wpdb query after a user registers.
What I am trying to do is to make 2 different custom post types if a user is a freelancer or an employer.

here is the code:

```
add_action('user_register','registration_funtion', 999);
function registration_funtion($uid){
global $wpdb;
        $existsD = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare(
                "SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id = '%s' AND meta_key = 'user_reg_type'" , $uid
            ));
 if($existsD = "userfreelancer"){
                
                $my_post_2 = array(
                    'post_title' => sanitize_text_field($user_info->user_login),
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'post_author' => $uid,
                    'post_type' => 'freelancer',
                    'post_content' => $existsD.'-'.$uid 
                    
                );
$freelancer_id = wp_insert_post($my_post_2);
} elseif($existsD = "useremployer") { 
                
                $my_post = array(
                    'post_title' => sanitize_text_field($user_info->user_login),
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'post_author' => $uid,
                    'post_type' => 'employer',
                    'post_content' => $existsD.'-'.$uid                  
                );
        
                $company_id = wp_insert_post($my_post);
}
```

Problem is its just takes the first if statement and completely ignores the else if statement.

Thanks in advance.
Regards,

Comment: Your `if` condition is setting the `$existsD` and not comparing it, `=` is to set, `==` is to compare

Comment: With double == its still didnt work

Comment: Do a check for what `$existsD`, you can use php [error_log](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php). Also, instead of hardcodeing the table prefix, `wp_`, you can use `$wpdb->prefix`, that way if your table prefix is anything but wp_ it will output the correct one

Comment: No related errors there in error_log

Comment: Now its making both post types :-(

Comment: @mysticalghoul, did you also change the `=` in your `elseif` condition (`elseif($existsD = "useremployer")` ? And have you checked if `$existsD` contains any of the meta values specified in your code? Also, "I am trying to access user meta by $wpdb query" - why must you use raw SQL, or why didn't you use [`get_user_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/)?

Comment: I tried using get_user_meta but its returns empty

Comment: How did you add the user meta? Using a plugin? Via custom coding - and if so, can you show your code?

Comment: if ( !is_wp_error( $uid ) ) { // check if insert was successful
                    add_user_meta( $uid, 'user_reg_type', sanitize_text_field($params['fl_user_role']) ); // add the meta
                }

Comment: In what hook you run that code? Because it seems that you might be adding the meta *after* the `user_register` hook is fired. Also, can you reply by editing your post and add your code to the post. And also, please tag me when you reply so that I get a notification of your reply, @mysticalghoul.

Comment: @SallyCJ Resolved it, apparently the user_register hook does not read the newly added meta so I used create post function in signup function.